# How to make the loop ignore looping a blank value?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

i use this loop to extract images from articles to put it in image gallery..so i want to 
Beyond or ignore the var $image if not contain image ..In other words,i dont need to print $image or leave  blanck space within the gallery..thanks for helping

```
        <?php
                    $count = 0;
            // loop through and display format
            foreach($articles as $article):
                // stripes the table by adding a class to every other row
                $class = ( ($count % 2) ? " class='altrow'": '' );

                $regex = '/src="(.*?)"/';
  preg_match_all($regex, $article['Article']['content'], $matches);
  $matches = $matches[1];
  foreach($matches as &$match)
     $match = substr($match, strrpos($match, '/') + 1);
    $image  =(implode($matches ));
            ?>

    <li>    <?php
    if(isset($image) && $image != ""){
  e( $html->link( $html->image(image ,array('height'=>'75px', 'width'=>'75px')),array('action' => 'view', $article['Article']['id']),array('escape' => false)));
  }else{

/// What is supposed to put here ///


  }
   ?></li>



            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Dude, format that code.  Hurts the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an if statement to check to image is empty. If it is, use the continue statement described and demonstrated here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

The continue key word will jump to the next iterateration.